# Launch External Process then Inject dll to it

Tags: code-injection, external-process

I have a game, the client of a game online, that game is wrote by another man, not me.
I want to inject a dll to this game for anti-hack from player!
I renamed the game.exe to Loader.dat
I want to write a game.exe (fake) call loader.dat to run then inject my dll in its process (loader.dat process)
How can i do it?
I have read some suggestion about run ext program, and inject dll to another process!
But it is 2 different project, I tried to join into one project! I false much time before i ask this question in here!

Comment: AND PLEASE STOP SHOUTING IN YOUR TITLES

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* do this. Even if you could "inject" some DLL into the game, since the game knows nothing about the DLL, the DLL will never be invoked.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sure that this dll can run good with that dll ^^  I have use wininject 1.7 to inject that dll into game process, and it work perfectly  But I don't want the client player must do it again and again when start game O_o

Comment: It has nothing to do with "run good". How will the code in the new DLL get executed?

Comment: That dll run alone from game, it detect hack tools load or not to system! and close the game O_o

Comment: I found the code of injection in this link! but I don't know to apply it to my project O_o http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet407.htm